# Problemas para setar um adapter na list

Tags: android, android-activity

Preciso criar uma lista dinâmica, não entendo bem como faz, algumas pessoas me falaram que se faz com `adapter` e assim estou tentando fazer.

De acordo com break point meus dados estão chegando perfeitamente, e todos ele estão sendo setados corretamente em minha Entidade.

Primeira mente chamo uma função com sucesso da resposta do JSON, e como disse, nela tenho certeza que esta sendo feito da maneira correta, programei ela da seguinte forma:

```
private void sucessoResposta(String json) {
   Comentarios comentariosRetorno = null;
   try {
        comentariosRetorno = JSONParser.parseComentarios(json);
        lstComentarios = comentariosRetorno.getComentarios();
        configurarAdapter();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MessageUtil.showError(getApplication(), R.string.erro_desconhecido);
    }
}
```

Na função`configurarAdapter()` faço assim:

```
 private void configurarAdapter() {
    adapter = new GenericAdapter<>(getParent(), lstComentarios,R.layout.item_comentario);
    adapter.setOnGetViewEvent(this);
    lisComentarios.setAdapter(adapter);
    lisComentarios.setEmptyView(lytEmptyComentarios);
}
```

Quando estou `debugando` o código ele para na primeira linha depois do `private void`

Tive que implementar a classe `onGetView` porém dentro dela não adicionei nada dentro dela ficando assim:

```
@Override
public void onGetView(Comentarios item, View view, boolean isNewView, int position) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de tentar muitas vezes, tive exito, eram um conjunto de coisas que precisavam a serem feitas:

1º não defini minha view no meu `onCreate`

```
lisComentarios = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lisComentarios);
lytEmptyComentarios = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lytEmptyComentarios);
```

2º alterei o parametro que estou passando, fiz assim:

```
adapter = new GenericAdapter<>(this,lstComentarios,R.layout.item_comentario);
```

Com isto solucionei meu problema.